# Writing dynamic formulas through Apps Script

Tags: dynamic, google-apps-script, google-sheets, formula

So I basically have this type of a setup for multiple spreadsheets:

```
    A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S
  1            Lab1     Lab2     Lab3      Averages
  2 FN LN    Lb HW Pa Lb HW Pa Lb HW Pa    Lb HW Pa Overall
  3 ab cd    12 34 56 78 90 01 23 45 67     x  y  z   xyz
  4 ef gh    89 09 87 76 54 32 18 48 39     x  y  z   xyz
  5 ij kl    10 29 83 47 31 24 35 49 54     x  y  z   xyz
  6   Ave    Av Av Av Av Av Av Av Av Av    Av Av AV  AveTot
```

The first two columns are "First" and "Last" name. "Lb", "HW", & "Pa" are just categories for each lab. Where the "x", "y", & "z" are averages of the categories respectively. The "Overall" "xyz" is the weighted sum of the categories' average. (x, y, & z) They are not necessarily the same weight. ie. They may be 25%, 25%, 50% or whatever combination totals up to 100% for "xyz" in the "Overall."

Now to calculate the categories' averages, I need to, for example for the name "ab cd," average 12, 78, & 23 to get "x." 34, 90, & 45 for "y." etc.

Now to set the formula manually for x, I can do this: `=AVERAGE(D2,G2,J2)`.
But the problem I'm encountering, trying to do it through *Apps Script*, is that ranges can only be selected continuously not discrete. (I may be mistaken.)

Also note that the "labs" can be more or less. And another dimension is that the categories can be more or less than the three shown.

So here is my question: How can I script in a formula for x, y, & z with "labs" & categories independently varying from spreadsheet to spreadsheet..?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this example will help you:

```
function test() {
  var result = getCells("A3,C3");
  Logger.log(result);
}

function getCells(cellsStr) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Spread Sheet URL")
  var cellsArray = [];
  var cells = cellsStr.split(",");
  for(var index in cells) {    
    var row = sheet.getRange(cells[index]).getValue();    
    cellsArray.push(row);
  }
  return cellsArray;
};
```